# How to strip characters by argument?

Tags: shell, filter

I want to filter *any* comma and *any* double quote mark from output by some command with.
For some entries.

Pseudocode:

```bsh
removechar --any -, -"
```

Current output could look like any of these

> lorem, ipsum " dolor ,"
> ",,lorem,, ipsum ,,, """ dolor ","
> ,lorem ipsum ,,, """ dolor ,

Desired output:

> lorem ipsum dolor
> lorem ipsum dolor
> lorem ipsum dolor

### Update

I might also need to remove any redundant whitespace character, for example:

```
a, b"
```

will become

```
ab
```

### Question

How to strip characters by argument?

Comment: really basic sed usage! `sed  's/[, \'"´\`]//g' < inputfile > outputfile `

Comment: I don't think it's basic at all. I don't understand what you did there. I am not a shell expert if it matters. I also think that the punctuation mark is redundant. Hopefully you didn't try to insult anyone not in your level because it's not a way to make the world better.

Comment: That's why I wrote an answer even before you said you don't understand what I'm doing there :) The "basic" wasn't meant to be condescending, it was meant to say, "if you of `sed`, that's one of the very basic things you can do with it. It can do more, but your problem is one of the things you typically solve with it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tr`:

```
<input tr -d ',"' >output
```

or, to remove the comma and quote characters *and* squeeze adjacent spaces (as shown in your desired output)

```
<input tr -d ',"' | tr -s ' ' >output
```

or more generally to remove all punctuation and squeeze all horizontal whitespace

```
<input tr -d '[:punct:]' | tr -s '[:blank:]' >output
```

Comment: So that's the utility I vaguely recalled from a few years back. Cool.

Comment: I have edited my question and added `without deleted characters being replaced with whitespace characters`, that's "squeezing whitespaces" right?

Comment: @Lahor characters deleted with `tr -d` are not replaced with whitespace characters; however if you consider `ipsum ,,, """ dolor` it will have 3 adjacent spaces once all the commas and quotes are removed. Squeezing collapses *those*.

Comment: Oh, yes, it was so trivial for me that I forgot to mention that. What a shame on me ! Oh I came out so stupid ! Trying to present a better question for future readers, I have edited the question post accordingly.

Comment: `tr -d '[,"]'` removes brackets too, though. You just want `tr -d ',"'` there.

Comment: @DonHolgo oops thanks - fixed

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into `sed`, and very basic regular expressions.

```bsh
sed  's/[, \'"´`]//g'
```

has the syntax

```
sed  's/[, \'"´`]//g'
      ^-------------- s like search&replace
       ^------------- the thing we want to search for and what we 
                      replace it with are separated by /
        ^-------^---- [] in a regular expression means
                      "any of the things in these []"
         ^^^^^^^----- in this case, the things to replace are commas,
                      spaces, single quotes, double quotes, slanted
                      quotes
                 ^--- next thing is what we replace it with
                  ^-- we replace with nothing
                   ^- g is an option that means
                      "repeat until you're done on each line"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like can do the work:

```
 sed 's/"//g; s/,//g' input_file >output_file
```